# Regular expression to match integer literal

Tags: java, regex, integer, literals

I was thinking about parsing a list of integers (from a property string). However, I would like to go beyond just positive and negative decimal values and parse *any* string that indicates [a Java integer literal (JLS 17)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) as can be found in source code. Similarly, I would like to be lenient with regards to any prefixes, separators and appendices around the integers themselves. In other words, I want to find them using repeated calls to [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

Is there a regular expression that matches all possible Java integer literals? It doesn't need to check the upper and lower bounds.

---

Even though I did explicitly link to the JLS, I'll show some valid and invalid numbers:

- `-1`: the `1` is matched, but the minus is an unary operator (I'll adjust if necessary)
- `0x00_00_00_0F`: the value fifteen is matched as hex digits, with an underscore to separate the two nibbles
- `0b0000_1111`: the value fifteen in binary is matched
- `017`: the octal value of fifteen is matched

Comment: There is a detailed regex for [Doubles](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)); perhaps you could prune that?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. Unfortunately it also doesn't allow the underscore, it says that it parses "simplifications".

Comment: Do you need to check the upper limit for a long (2^63) or an int with the pattern?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nah, that's not necessary. Just like with Java, I'll first match and then create an exception or similar if it is out of bounds. Edited the question for that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes does it need to be any more complicated than something like `-?([0-9]_*)*[0-9]`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, I also want to match hexadecimals and such. Of course, I could make use of the `|` (OR) construct for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

decimal:
`(?:0|[1-9](?:_*[0-9])*)[lL]?`

hexadecimal:
`0x[a-fA-F0-9](?:_*[a-fA-F0-9])*[lL]?`

octal:
`0[0-7](?:_*[0-7])*[lL]?`

binary:
`0[bB][01](?:_*[01])*[lL]?`

All together: (in freespacing mode)

```
(?:
    0
    (?:
        x [a-fA-F0-9] (?: _* [a-fA-F0-9] )*
      |
        [0-7] (?: _* [0-7] )*
      |
        [bB] [01] (?: _* [01] )*
    )?
  |
    [1-9] (?: _* [0-9] )*
)
[lL]?
```

[test it](https://regex101.com/r/bL6Gua/2/)

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would get me a long way. Does it allow multiple underscores though? Maybe that `?` should be a `*`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: As I understand the doc, underscores aren't supposed to be contigous, but perhaps I'am wrong? (in other words is `1____1` allowed ?). Note that the group inside which the optional underscore is, is eventually repeated.

Comment: Huh, can anybody rewrite that regex? I seemed to be able to update it (the test version still had the ? instead of the *)....

Comment: Thanks again, I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298057/589259) that parses the integer as well using the regular expression syntax based in spirit on your regex.

Answer (score 0):

After the answer from Casimir I decided to take it a bit further and implemented some code to actually parse the integers as well, included below. It does include the minus and plus symbols even though those are officially not part of the integer literal as described in the JLS; they are unary operators.

```
package nl.owlstead.ifprops;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class JavaIntegerParser {
    private static final Pattern BINARY = Pattern.compile("(0b)([01](?:_*[01])*)(L?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private static final Pattern OCTAL = Pattern.compile("(0)([0-7](?:_*[0-7])*)(L?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private static final Pattern DECIMAL = Pattern.compile("()(0|(?:[1-9](?:_*[0-9])*))(L?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    private static final Pattern HEXADECIMAL = Pattern.compile("(0x)([0-9a-f](?:_*[0-9a-f])*)(L?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   
    // NOTE: OCTAL should be before DECIMAL if this is used to find the pattern
    private static final Pattern SIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL = Pattern.compile(
            "(?:([+-])\\s*)?(" + 
            BINARY + "|" + OCTAL + "|" + DECIMAL + "|" + HEXADECIMAL + 
            ")", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
    public static int parseJavaInteger(String javaInteger) throws NumberFormatException {
        BigInteger value = parseIntegerAsBigInt(javaInteger);
        try {
            return value.intValueExact();
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Number is not between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE");
        }
    }
    
    public static long parseJavaLong(String javaLong) throws NumberFormatException {
        BigInteger value = parseIntegerAsBigInt(javaLong);
        try {
            return value.longValueExact();
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Number is not between Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE");
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger parseIntegerAsBigInt(String javaLiteral) {
        Matcher intMatcher = SIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL.matcher(javaLiteral);
        if (!intMatcher.matches()) {
            throw new NumberFormatException(javaLiteral + " is not recognized as a Java integer literal");
        }
        
        String signGroup = intMatcher.group(1);
        String prefixAndValueGroup = intMatcher.group(2);
        String radixGroup = "";
        String valueGroup = "";
        // String longGroup = "";
        List<Pattern> patterns = List.of(BINARY, OCTAL, DECIMAL, HEXADECIMAL);
        for (Pattern pattern : patterns) {
            Matcher specificMatcher = pattern.matcher(prefixAndValueGroup);
            if (specificMatcher.matches()) {
                radixGroup = specificMatcher.group(1);
                valueGroup = specificMatcher.group(2);
                // longGroup = specificMatcher.group(3);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (valueGroup == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Number both matches but doesn't contain a value (parser error)");
        }

        BigInteger sign = signGroup != null && signGroup.matches("-") ? BigInteger.ONE.negate() : BigInteger.ONE; 
        
        int radix;
        switch (radixGroup.toLowerCase()) {
        case "0b":
            radix = 2;
            break;
        case "0":
            radix = 8;
            break;
        case "":
            radix = 10;
            break;
        case "0x":
            radix = 16;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
 
        BigInteger value = new BigInteger(valueGroup.replaceAll("_", ""), radix).multiply(sign);
        return value;
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the code to find multiple integers from a string, but that didn't go well. The problem is that some invalid literals such as `0__0` got accepted as two literals with value zero; not exactly what you want. So please use the regex only to detect if a string is actually an integer and separate the integers e.g. using `String.split(SEPARATOR_REGEX)`.

Funny enough my Eclipse IDE did accept `0__0` as a literal even if it is officially not compliant to the JLS. Not a biggy, but weird none-the-less.

Comment: Quickly view your answer, sorry too tired to go more deep, but: take care to not use too much captures in particular if don't need them. Use non-capturing groups `(?:....)` (captures have a cost).

Comment: I do use non-capturing groups where possible. Maybe to validate the entire integer I could remove a few; I don't need them for the initial match. Or maybe I could remove the entire initial match and just leave the loop that validates all the possible formats. But hey, in the end we're trying to match integers, not pages and pages of text...

Answer (score -1):

Well.... in simplest terms, base 2, 8, and 10 number *could* use the same pattern since their values are all numeric characters. BUT, you probably want an expression for each type. The problem is that you did not make clear your intent. I am going on the assumption that you want the expression to validate what base a particular value is.

```
String base10Regex = "[0-9]+";
String base2Regex = "[0-1]+";
String base8Regex = "[0-7]+";
String base16Regex = "^[0-9A-F]+$";
```

For the octal and decimal values, you will need to prepend your expression to check for an optional sign character `"^[\\+|-]?"`. For hex values, if you expect the values to start with "0x", I will suggest to prepend the expression with those literal values.

Comment: No underscores and it doesn't match the actual integers. And of course the boundaries (`^$`) would not work with find, but it is a start...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you. I grant you the underscores, but what do you mean it doesn't match the actual integers? Also, I didn't know boundaries don't work with `find`. So, thank you for that as well.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant that it doesn't match the literals as indicated in the JLS, where you need to have the `0x` or `0X` for hexadecimals etc.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes except I wrote " if you expect the values to start with "0x", I will suggest to prepend the expression with those literal values"